# About MPM for Apache on windows

Tags: php, apache

I want to know how to change Apache MPM from mpm_winnt to prefork.

Because I use PHP 5.3 Non Thread Safe .

And I’ve heard prefork is more stable than thread model.

Comment: PHP has been thread safe for a very long tie. So have most of the extensions. Do you have any eivdence that this is not the case?

Comment: I use php-5.3.16-nts-win32-VC9-x86.msi. I thought nts means "non thread safe".
Also Apache’s official site http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/en/mpm.html said “sites requiring stability or compatibility with older software can use a prefork”.

Answer (score 6):

If I'm correct then you can't choose the mpm model on windows.

The following table lists the default MPMs for various operating systems. This will be the MPM selected if you do not make another choice at **compile-time.**

Netware : mpm_netware

OS/2    : mpmt_os2

Unix    : prefork, worker, or event, depending on platform capabilities

Windows : mpm_winnt

( refer to : http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/en/mpm.html )